# Can't instantiate Bean due to Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, javabeans

I am working on internationalizing a JSF web app. I have a SessionScoped bean (StringBean.java) which stores the locale, and I call this bean in other SessionScoped beans to retrieve the locale and get the right resource bundle. Using the StringBean in other beans looks something like:

```
@ManagedBean(name="samlBean")
public class SAMLBean extends BaseBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{stringbean}")
    private StringBean stringBean;    

    // getters and setters


    public void someMethod(){
        Locale currentLocale = new Locale(stringBean.getLanguageCode(), stringBean.getCountryCode());
        ResourceBundle errors = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.resources.MessagesBundle", currentLocale);

       // use resource bundle to get string in right locale
     }
```

This works just fine in several beans with no issue. However, I am trying to also use the StringBean in a RequestScoped bean in the exact same way, but I get the following error when browsing to a specific page:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/Federation] threw exception [Cant instantiate class: com.federation.beans.ConnectionBean.] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The null pointer is happening in the constructor of the RequestScoped bean, where a method inside the constructor is calling:

```
Locale currentLocale = new Locale(stringBean.getLanguageCode(), stringBean.getCountryCode());
```

For some reason the StringBean object is null, even though I have navigated to other pages where the StringBean is not null and the resource bundle is working.

I tried testing out what would happen if I made the RequestScoped bean into a SessionScoped bean, but it still didn't work.

Can anyone offer any insight or suggestions as to what is happening, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Check if you by accident assign it a null value somewhere

Comment: What is `extends BaseBean`?

Comment: @Tiny, it is not relevant to this question. I have beans that extend BaseBean while still properly accessing the StringBean object.

Comment: @Kukeltje, I don't ever assign the StringBean object to null.

Comment: is stringbean actually null or might one of the fields be null? (language or country?)

Comment: It seems that the stringbean is null. I checked the session, and it seems that the stringbean is still there in the session. Why would this bean be null?

Comment: I found the problem, I needed to use the @PostConstruct annotation and create an init method which called the methods to access the resource bundle, instead of directly calling these methods in the constructor.